# No Settings tab in Properties of XNA project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, settings

When I've created Windows forms projects I have been able to store variables for use on relaunch of an application by creating them in the Settings tab in the project properties. I am currently working on an XNA project and want to do something similar to save the 'Hi-Score' in the game. However, when I look in properties there is no Settings tab. Any idea if I can access this option in an XNA project?

Comment: My advise is to forget that idea and store the high score, and other values, on an xml file; making yourself sure that it will work regardless of the platform running your game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on your project in Solution Explorer, select Add -> Component, and find Settings File.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was after.